# Special cases in ideal source transformations for equivalent cirucits

Tags: current-source, voltage-source, ideal, equivalent-circuit

I don't exactly understand what's meant by these transformations. Are we supposed to replace one of the sources with a resistor? What's the resistor's value supposed to be?

I couldn't find sources about this anywhere.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the sources are ideal then no, you shouldn't regard the added resistor as meaningful. Please reference the source of the picture in your question (I believe it's mandatory to do so).

Comment: My professor gave it to us. I couldn't find it anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ideal voltage source has an equivalent resistance of \$0\Omega\$. An ideal current source has an equivalent resistance of \$\infty\Omega\$. This has some significant consequences when theorizing with them, and frankly allows you to make nonsense circuits as well.

For the first circuit, the voltage source is in series with the current source, which is akin to having a \$0\Omega\$ in series with a \$\infty\Omega\$ resistance, where the total resistance would then still be \$\infty\Omega\$. I.e. only the current source has a say in it. The voltage on the node between the two sources might be shifted by the voltage source but it doesn't matter because the current source is "isolating" it from the load. There is only one branch current and it is set by the current source.

For the second circuit, the voltage source is in parallel with the current source, which is akin to having a \$0\Omega\$ in parallel with an \$\infty\Omega\$ resistance, where the total resistance would be the \$0\Omega\$. I.e., only the voltage source has a say in it. The current prefers the path of least resistance, which is inevitably through the ideal voltage source. The voltage over the load is completely fixed by the voltage source, and so the only thing that counts is \$I = \frac{V}{R}\$ which becomes independent of the current source.

I do not know where the \$R_1\$ keeps coming from. In all given circuits, \$R_1\$ can be left out without changing its effect on \$V_A\$, \$V_B\$ or the current through \$R_y\$.